# How to read this string into jsoncpp 's Json::Value

Tags: jsoncpp

I  have such a json  string  :

```
{"status":0,"bridge_id":"bridge.1","b_party":"85267191234","ref_id":"20180104151432001_0","function":{"operator_profile":{"operator":"aaa.bbb"},"subscriber_profile":{"is_allowed":true,"type":8},"name":"ServiceAuthen.Ack"},"node_id":"aaa.bbb.collector.1"}
```

how  can  I read  it  into  jsoncpp  lib  's  Json::Value object ?

I  found  such code by searching  stackoverflow :

```
    std::string strJson = "{\"mykey\" : \"myvalue\"}"; // need escape the quotes

Json::Value root;   
Json::Reader reader;
bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( strJson.c_str(), root );     //parse process
if ( !parsingSuccessful )
{
    std::cout  << "Failed to parse"
           << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages();
    return 0;
}
std::cout << root.get("mykey", "A Default Value if not exists" ).asString() << std::endl;
return 0;
```

but  how to  convert  my  string to  this  form ?

```
{\"mykey\" : \"myvalue\"}
```

thank  you  for any  help  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

The slash characters are escape characters used to represent a `"` in C++ **source code** (without them the `"` would mean "This is the end of this C++ string literal").

The JSON (which isn't C++ source code) should not have the escape characters in it.